# Dropdown to change the page refresh

Tags: refresh

I'm looking for a way to add a dropdown in Confluence to give the user the ability to either turn off the ability to auto-refresh the content, or set the intervals to 2 minutes, 5 minutes, 10 minutes or 15 minutes.

I was playing around with the meta tags and was thinking I could perhaps do something like this:`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="+refresh_param+">`
However, it does not seem to actually use the param created. Is there another way to do this?

The page is designed to show serveral graphs for monitoring purposes. So really only the graphs need to be refreshed. With that in mind, I also tried just adding the &ar='+refresh_param+' to the img, but no luck as well.

I'm fairly new to this and would love any input anyone might have. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You can use Javascript code to refresh the page on intervals. Try `setInterval`

Comment: So is `setInterval('window.location.reload()', 'refresh_param');` what you are recommending?

Answer (score 0):

You should use code:

```
setInterval('window.location.reload()', 'refresh_param'); // where refresh_param is time in milliseconds after which refresh will be done.
```

You can use `setTimeout('window.location.reload()', 'refresh_param');` as we need that one time only